# In Spring-Boot 4, trying to inject property file values

Tags: java, spring-boot, properties-file

Basically, all I want to do is to inject values from my application.properties file into a POJO. I have tried it a bunch of different ways, including using the @Value annotation, trying to @Autowite the Environment, and using @ConfigurationProperties to map the properties entries to like named fields. In all cases, I can't get the injection to work.

Strangely, I was able to get an injection does easily using just the @Value annotation in one of my form controllers. I did try annotation the POJO as @Service.

The code pasted below reflects my latest attempt using the @ConfigurationProperties annotation but has commented out code for the earlier tries.

I expect I missed something very fundamental but I can't see what and I would greatly appreciate some help.  Thanks!

```
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.rabbitmq.client.Channel;
import com.rabbitmq.client.Connection;
import com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory;

//@Configuration
//@ComponentScan(basePackages = "xxx.xxx.ua")
//@PropertySource(value = {"classpath:application.properties"})

@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(locations="classpath:application.properties", ignoreUnknownFields=false, prefix="rabbit")
public class Rabbit 
{
    //@Value("${rabbit_un}")
    private String user;

    //@Value("${rabbit-pw}")
    private String password;

    //@Value("${rabbit-queue}")
    private String queue;

    //@Value("${rabbit-host}")
    private String host;

    private Connection connection;
    private Channel channel;



/*
 * PropertySourcesPlaceHolderConfigurer Bean only required for @Value("{}") annotations.
 * Remove this bean if you are not using @Value annotations for injecting properties.
 */
/*
@Bean
public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
    return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
}
*/  

public Rabbit()
{

    ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();

    //rabbitUn = "guest";
    //rabbitPassword = "guest";
    //rabbitHost = "72.xx.xx.xx";
    //rabbitQueue = "hello";

    factory.setUsername(user);
    factory.setPassword(password);
    factory.setHost(host);

    try 
    {
        connection = factory.newConnection();
        channel = connection.createChannel();

        channel.queueDeclare(queue, false, false, false, null);

        Logger.getGlobal().fine(() -> "Successfully connected to RabbitMQ");
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
Logger.getGlobal().severe(() -> "FAILED connecting to RabbitMQ");
    }


    // channel.close();
    // connection.close();
}

void logLoginUserNameNotFound(String s)
{
}

void logLoginBadPassword(String s)
{
}


void logLoginSuccess(String s)
{
}

private void send(String s)
{
}
}
```

The properties file:

```
# Control what port the Sprint Boot app will be listening on
server.port=8080

# Disable Tomcat session timeout
server.session-timeout=-1

# Application specific properties
enable_admin_server=false

rabbit.user=guest
rabbit.password=guest
rabbit.queue=hello
rabbit.host=72.xx.xx.xx

# Valid choices are: SEVERE, WARNING, INFO, CONFIG, FINE, FINER, FINEST
logger_lever=FINE
```

Comment: You are using Spring Boot, simply add `spring-boot-starter-rabbitmq` and inject a `AmqpTemplate` or `ConnectionFactory` that is already configured for you by Spring Boot, no need to do it yourself. Regarding the logger I strongly suggest using the `slf4j` facade instead of JUL directly especially with Spring Boot.

Answer (score 2):

The problem here turned out to be that Spring does not inject the values until after the object is created. That is, the constructor was being called before the values were handed to the POJO.

I solved the issue by removing the constructor, and adding a method to do what the constructor would have done. I then annotated this method with @PostConstruct, which caused the method to be called after the values were injected. Lesson learned.

Comment: How would spring inject values into an instance that isn't even there as it is being created... This is just how java works, you can only work with a fully constructed object, if you try to access uninitialized values it will fail. It is basically the same as trying to access a `DataSource` in the constructor that first needs to be set trough a setter method, it isn't going to be available in the constructor.